# What are “ad hoc” reviewers/referees for journals?

Tags: journals, peer-review, terminology

What are “ad hoc” reviewers/referees for journals? Is this a different role from (regular) reviewers/referees? If yes, how are they different?

I see some people use the term *ad hoc* somewhere in the referee-service section of their CV, and some people don’t. Is there any difference? What is the proper practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ad hoc* might be used in the context of conference review where reviews are usually done by the members of a Program Committee and an extra (usually a specialized expert) reviewer is brought in for one or two papers which require careful review beyond the capability or capacity of the PC members. I haven't seen it used in the context of a journal.